# HTTP POST API response without waiting for email notifications to complete Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, api, jakarta-mail

In my Spring boot controller, I am having a method that inserts some records to the backend, at the end of this operation, I notify the user via Javax email based on the response received from from previous operation. 
Currently I get response from API after email method completes.
Is there any way I can return response to the client once my first operation is completed while email notification happens in background

I tried already implement Async annotation in sendemail method of mail service. But I cannot find any difference in response time and I still get the response only after the email is sent.
My pseudo code
Controller:

```
@Autowired
private EmailService emailService;

@PostMapping(value = "create", produces = "text/plain")
private insertRecord()
{
 response = <Insert into DB>;
 sendEmail(response);
}

private sendEmail(response)
{
  //check if email should be sent and if yes
  emailservice.send(response);  
}
```

Email service:

```
@Service
public class EmailService {

@Async
public static void sendEmail(MailEvent mailEvent) throws IOException {//send 
email}
}
```

Starter
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAsync
    public class Starter {...}

Answer (score 2):

i didn't notice my async method was designed as static, removing static works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think Spring Async is the way to go to solve your problem. Did you you also enable the async functionality with `@EnableAsync` and create an Executor bean? See this guide for the full tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: what I was missing is the taskexecutor however even if I add I do not see any change in the behaviour. I also gave a name to bean like @Bean(name="processExecutor") and mentioned that name in Async method as  
@Async("processExecutor")
    public static void sendEmail(MailEvent mailEvent) throws IOException {}